# How to adjust the positioning of \cancel strikethrough?

Tags: packages, cancel

After loading the package `cancel` the command `\cancel{text}` worked not so exactly, because the slash strikethrough looks so ugly.

The output is shown below:

[image]

Is it a LaTeX error or PDF error?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), if you are referring to a specific portion of a code, please add a [Minimum Workig Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) that can be compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\cancel{\text{TeX}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. With your code, i found out that the problem comes from \usepackage{pict2e}. It made the slash athwart.

Comment: \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
Now, it work: \\ [5pt]
\cancel{\textbf{Text}}

\end{document}